# Including information from one database into another - MS Access

Tags: database, microsoft-access, forms

I have created a new table in MS Access which, for my purposes here, I'll call Table A.  It contains a ton of information that staff need to enter for each company or individual. The forms are time consuming to complete and so, I thought, to save them a bit of time, many of those company and individual names already exist in the contacts database, so they could simply enter in the last name (or company name) and it would get the info from the contacts database and populate the field. And that works great if the client's name is already in the contacts database.

However, some names are new and don't exist in the contacts database.

If they have to go to the contacts database (or the form for it) and enter in the contact name and address, THEN go to Table A and enter in all the information associated with it, it won't be a time saver at all.

There must be a way, if the name doesn't exist, for a form to pop up so the user can add that information  which would then populate the contacts database so that it would then populate Table A.

Does anyone know how to do that?  Or if it's possible?  I'm self-taught, and a novice user.

Thank you!

Lori

Answer (score 0):

First, don't store two copies of the same information in two tables or databases. That's a recipe for inconsistent data.

You can link a table from your contacts database (assuming it is also in Access) under the "External Data tab" by clicking the "Access" button. Then all the info from the contacts database will be available in the database with table A.

Next just create a form with a dropdown that selects from the contacts table from the contacts database, you can add a button next to the dropdown to popup a form on click and insert a new row if the user can't find the name they want in the dropdown.